# Can't execute a query with the right syntax using mysql.connector 8.0 in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to set up a small database for a simple card game using mysql.connector 8.0 in jupyter notebook, yet I can't execute any queries, it says that the syntax is wrong even though it's all good.

That's the code:
'''

```
import random
import collections
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='*****',
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password',
    database='CardGame'
    )

cur = conn.cursor()
query = "CREATE TABLE cards (id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,rank VARCHAR(1),suit VARCHAR(10))"
cur.execute(query)
conn.commit()
```

'''

That's the error I keep getting:

ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank VARCHAR(1), suit VARCHAR(10))' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an access to a MySQL database at the moment but your create table has `RANK` as a column name which is also a keyword. Can you change that to something else and try it out?